# Check Interrupt Level Mips

Tags: mips, interrupt

Im writing an interrupt handler that takes keyboard interrupts and inputs them into a function in the program for a homework assignment.  The current step I am on is:

Check the interrupt level. The MMIO Receiver Control interrupt is a hardware 
interrupt at level 1, which is the lowest (rightmost) bit in the interrupt masks in Fig. B.7.{1,2}, 
which is bit 8 = 0x0100. For this HW, we don’t care about any other interrupt levels, so if it 
doesn’t match this one, do nothing and exit.

I want to know how I go about that.  So far my interrupt is like this:

```
.ktext 0x80000180

Interrupt: 
sw $at, saveat
sw $a0, save0
sw $a1, save1
mfc0 $k0, $13       #$k0 = Cause
mfc0 $k1, $14       #$k1 = EPC
andi $k0, $k0, 0x003c   # $k0 = Exception Code
bnez $k0, done      # If its not equal 0, its not a keyboard interrupt, done
```

At this point I need to check the interrupt level, but I am unsure how this is actually done in code.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k0 is your cause, I would assume that stores the level as well.  What about doing something like this?

```
  andi $t0, $k0, 0x003c # $t0 = Exception code, $k0 is preserved
  bnez $t0, done        #If its not equal 0, its not a keyboard interrupt, done
  andi $t0, $k0, 0x0100 #Check to see if this bit is set in $k0
  bnez $t0, done        #If it is set, service the interrupt
                        #otherwise, go to done

  #service the interrupt

done:
  #clean up and exit
```

Comment: Oh, I never saw your comment afterwords last year, but yes at the time I understood it.  Haven't used MIPS since this assignment, so a little fuzzy on it now, but get the general idea!